# VB.NET Call a procedure in another form from different form

Tags: vb.net, forms

Would just like some advice with how best to do this as everything I've tried isn't quite working how I like.

I have a main form which has some stats on in the form of labels and have a procedure called UpdateStats() which is in the code for this form (frmMain) when bring up the edit form and make changes and close it I'd like this UpdateStats to execute again, frmMain is not hidden or closed during the edit process.

I've tried using the GotFocus event of the form but this doesn't seem to fire even when adding frmMain.Focus before the Me.Close on the edit form.

I've also tried using the Activate event of the form but this then calls the UpdateStats() procedure on the initial opening of the application which causes problem because at this stage their is nothing to calculate stats for so am left with object instance errors etc.

Also if possible I'd like not to make it a public function because the UpdateStats() function sets the text property to quite a few labels and using lots of controls which will  mean passing a lot of a parameters but if there's no other way of doing this then I may have to do that.

I was thinking possibly using the Activated event of the form which is discusssed above but doing an IF statement to use a My.Settings boolean variable to know whether to update it or not to prevent the errors on application load.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Make it public and call it.  You'll need a reference to the form instance which might be a problem if you are using default instances.

Comment: Thank you for this, please see my latest update as to why if possible I'd like to avoid this.

Comment: okay, well create a new public method called `UpdateDisplay()` which takes no parameters.  Have it call UpdateStatus.  Call UpdateDisplay from whereever and whenever you want.  It is essentially what you describe as triggering some event which calls it.